# Manually Add Row Values to Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, gridview, datagridview

I have a winform app, where in i have a grid view that is supposed to search data from database and display to a gridview.

here is my code to create columns and add row values to it..

```
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    DataGridViewColumn ad = new DataGridViewColumn();
                    DataGridViewCell cell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell(); //Specify which type of cell in this column
                    ad.CellTemplate = cell;
                    ad.HeaderText = "Serial No";
                    ad.Name = "Serial No";
                    ad.Visible = true;
                    dataGridView2.Columns.Add(ad);
                    DataGridViewColumn ad1 = new DataGridViewColumn();
                    DataGridViewCell cell1 = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell(); //Specify which type of cell in this column
                    ad1.CellTemplate = cell1;
                    ad1.HeaderText = "Enrollment No.";
                    ad1.Name = "Enrollment No.";
                    ad1.Visible = true;
                    dataGridView2.Columns.Add(ad1);
                    DataGridViewColumn ad2 = new DataGridViewColumn();
                    DataGridViewCell cell2 = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell(); //Specify which type of cell in this column
                    ad2.CellTemplate = cell1;
                    ad2.HeaderText = "Student Name";
                    ad2.Name = "Studen Name";
                    ad2.Visible = true;
                    dataGridView2.Columns.Add(ad2);
                    DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
                    row.CreateCells(dataGridView2);
                    row.Cells[0].Value = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
                    row.Cells[1].Value = dr.GetValue(1).ToString();
                    row.Cells[2].Value = dr.GetValue(2).ToString();
                    //row.Cells[3].Value = dr.GetValue(3).ToString();
                    //row.Cells[4].Value = dr.GetValue(4).ToString();
                    //row.Cells[5].Value = dr.GetValue(5).ToString();
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
                    i++;
                }
```

i have created 3 columns and i'm trying to store three values from database to the three corresponding cells.

but while executing i get the following error

> No row can be added to a DataGridView control that does not have columns. Columns must be added first.

what am i doing wrong? 
Please let me know. thanks in advance for all your help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem :** You are Adding the columns to `dataGridView2` but finally you are trying to add the rows to `dataGridView1`.

**Solution :** if your intention isto add the rows to the `dataGridView2` replace the follwing statement

Replace This:

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
```

With This:

```
dataGridView2.Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: @REZR.AMX: You are welcome :) mark it as answer if its helpful